# Firebase: How to handle click on notification if notification was sent by server

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I am sending a notification to an Android device with my Java backend.

The Android device receives the notification and when I click on it, it simply opens my app.

So far so good, but what I would like to achieve is to be able to read the data from the Firebase message in the onCreate() method of the MainActivity class. How would that be possible?

```
private fun sendNotification(messageBody: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        val channelId = "" // TODO CHANNEL ID NEEDED
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
```

This doesn't log anything for me (in onCreate()):

```
if (getIntent() != null) {
       val dataBundle = getIntent().extras
       Log.d("data bundle", dataBundle.toString())
   }
```

Comment: How are you sending the notifiaction from Firebase? You should see if you need the context for getIntent().

Comment: Like suggested in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#java with `setNotification()`

Answer (score 1):

At first, check the 2 different types of notifications that you can send. [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Depending on each type and the state of your app (background or Foreground) you cannot always take the data from a Notification, check this for more [link2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).

When your application gets a notification there is a service with a method you can override to get the data. The method is called OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage), you can find more info about the service at [link2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).

That's the way to get the data of a notification. If you want the data on your Activity there are some ways you could achieve that. You could try to save them at a Database(persistent) or at [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) and access them when your Activity starts or you could pass the data through the bundle to the activity you are about to open(Deeplinks), check this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51767478/timeline).

Comment: Alright, thanks. But what if I want a specific action to be done when the app is in the background and the notification is clicked on?

Comment: You can do that with the PendingIndend. Instead of your MainActivity create an IntentService class. For examble : 

`public class SimpleTaskIntent extends IntentService {

    public SimpleTaskIntent() {
        super("SimpleTaskIntent");
 }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null) return;
        MyData data = (MyData) intent.getSerializableExtra("my_data");
        if (data == null) return;
  
  //Do something with your data...
        
    }
}`
**Don't forget to add the service at your manifest.**